# What is total distance travelled by plane on two different speeds.

Tags: physics

I was trying to solve a question today.

An aircraft travels at a speed of 180mph during the first half and at a speed of 460mph during the second half of its route. Total flight time is 04:15 hours. What is the distance between airport of departure and arrival.

Now the answer to this is 1100 miles.Would anyone mind to help me understand how we can get to this answer? The final formula would be: x = v1*t - (v1 - v2) * (v1t/(v1+v2))
The solution involved 42 lines of rewrites of formulas, but I am trying to understand it conceptually without having to rewrite it all.

Comment: $42$ lines?  That's hard to imagine.  Does "first half" refer to time or to distance?  Assuming it refers to distance, then:  how long does the first half take? how long does the second half take?

Comment: Half the distance or half the flight time?

Comment: @herbsteinberg its half the route. I know that sounds ambigous, but for half the flight time it would be delta(x) = v1 + v2 / delta(t) and thats not 1100miles

Comment: @lulu sorry for screenshots, but cant copy it.  
http://puu.sh/DGKZC/9281d52637.png  
http://puu.sh/DGKZQ/cc9d8ecf82.png

Answer (score 1):

$t_1 = \frac{x}{2v_1}$

$t_2 = \frac{x}{2v_2}$

$t_1 + t_2 = \frac{17}{4}$

You know $v_1$ and $v_2$  Find x comes to $1099.6875 \approx 1100$ miles

$\frac{x}{2v_1}+\frac{x}{2v_2} = \frac{17}{4}$

$ x\left(\frac{v_1+v_2}{2v_1v_2}\right) =\frac{17}{4}$

$x = \frac{180\times460\times17\times2}{640\times4} = 1100$

Comment: Can u clarify how I would solve this algebraiicly? 
I would have to substitute t1 and t2 in the third equation, and then solve for x, but I am having difficulties with moving over the 2v1, and 2v2 to the 17/4 side.

Answer (score 0):

We have:
$$
\frac d2\left(\frac 1 {v_1}+ \frac 1 {v_2}\right)=t\implies
d=\frac {2v_1v_2}{v_1+v_2}t.$$

Comment: Could u explain to me how u derived the first part from the "story"?

Comment: @RowandeGraaf $t_i=(d/2)/v_i,\ t_1+t_2=t $.

Answer (score 0):

You have the speeds $v_1$ and $v_2$ on each of the two parts of the route, you have the total flight time $t$ for both parts of the route, you have that the distance of each part of the route was half the total distance, and you want to know the total distance $x.$

So if the times on the first and second parts were $t_1$ and $t_2$
and the distances were $x_1$ and $x_2$ respectively, then
\begin{align}
x_1 &= x_2 = \frac x2,  \tag1\\
x_1 &= v_1 t_1,\tag2\\
x_2 &= v_2 t_2,\tag3\\
t &= t_1 + t_2.\tag4
\end{align}

We have $\frac x2$ in Equation $(1)$ because we were told we had a *first half*
and a *second half* of the route.

Now from Equations $(2)$ and $(3)$ we have
\begin{align}
t_1 &= \frac{x_1}{v_1},\tag5\\
t_2 &= \frac{x_2}{v_2}.\tag6
\end{align}

Use Equation $(1)$ to substitute for $x_1$ and $x_2$:
\begin{align}
t_1 &= \frac{x/2}{v_1},\tag7\\
t_2 &= \frac{x/2}{v_2}.\tag8
\end{align}

Add Equations $(7)$ and $(8)$ to get
$$ t_1 + t_2 = \frac{x/2}{v_1} + \frac{x/2}{v_2}
 = \frac x2\left( \frac{1}{v_1} + \frac{1}{v_2} \right). \tag9$$

Recalling that $t_1 + t_2 = t,$
$$ t = \frac x2\left( \frac{1}{v_1} + \frac{1}{v_2} \right). \tag{10}$$

Solve for $x$:
$$ x = \frac{2t}{\frac{1}{v_1} + \frac{1}{v_2}}. \tag{11} $$

Technically, that's a completely solution. Just plug in the known data on the right hand side of Equation $(11)$ and compute.
But we can clear the fractions in the denominator on the right-hand side of $(11)$
by multiplying by $v_1$ and multiplying by $v_2$:
$$ x = \frac{2v_1v_2t}{v_2 + v_1}. \tag{12} $$

That's the same result as both the other answers, just derived in more detail;
a lot more detail that most people would give.
For example, you could start with Equations $(4),$ $(7),$ and $(8)$ and work from there.

Now let's take a look at the right-hand side of the solution you were given:

$$v_1 t - (v_1 - v_2) \left(\frac{v_1 t}{v_1 + v_2}\right). $$

Multiply $v_1 - v_2$ into the numerator of the fraction on the right,:
$$v_1 t - (v_1 - v_2) \left(\frac{v_1 t}{v_1 + v_2}\right) =
v_1 t - \frac{(v_1 - v_2) v_1t}{v_1 + v_2}. $$

Put everything over a common denominator:
$$v_1 t - \frac{(v_1 - v_2) v_1t}{v_1 + v_2} 
= \frac{(v_1 + v_2)v_1 t - (v_1 - v_2) v_1t}{v_1 + v_2} .$$

Simplify:
\begin{align}
 \frac{(v_1 + v_2)v_1 t - (v_1 - v_2) v_1t}{v_1 + v_2}
&= \frac{(v_1^2 t + v_2v_1 t) - (v_1^2 t - v_2v_1t)}{v_1 + v_2}\\
&= \frac{v_1^2 t + v_2v_1 t - v_1^2 t + v_2v_1t}{v_1 + v_2}\\
&= \frac{2v_1v_2 t}{v_1 + v_2}.
\end{align}

Notice that this is the same as the right-hand side of Equation $(12).$
So the solutions agree although they use different sequences of operations
in their derivations.

The actual sequence of operations on the solution sheet looks like someone almost randomly trying to combine the equations in many different ways until something clicks. This is a legitimate thing to try if you don't have any better idea how to solve a problem, but it's a bit strange to see this from someone who (one would think) is supposed to be teaching the material.

---

Here's an approach that I find a bit more intuitive.
Notice that the speed on the second half of the route is
$\frac{460}{180} = \frac{23}{9}$ times as fast as the speed on the first half.
That means the second half of the route takes $\frac{9}{23}$ times as long a time to fly as the first half, because the distances were equal and time is inversely proportional to speed over a given distance.

That also means the two parts of the route divide the total time period
in the ratio $23 : 9$ (to make the second part $\frac{9}{23}$ as much as the first part).
Imagine dividing the total time into $32$ equal parts; then you can use $23$ of them to fly the first half of the route and $9$ to fly the second half.
So you spend $\frac{9}{32}$ of the total time flying the second half of the route. Now consider that the total flying time is $4.25$ hours, that means you spend
$$ \frac{9}{32} \times 4.25 = 1.1953125 $$
hours on that half of the route.
During that time you fly at $460$ miles per hour, so the distance covered is
$$460 * 1.1953125 = 549.84375 $$
miles. Multiply by $2$ to get the length of the entire route and not just one half of it.

Comment: Amazing. I had issues getting from (7+8) to (12). Furthermore, I was looking for a solution you are given as intuitifly. Math solves everything but for the test I was preparing for "seeing" these ratios is of the essence (then again, if you are as quick as u with math, then its not necessary.) Amazing!